# R proc.time - strange behavior in for loop

Tags: r

When I run this code

```
X <- 100
M <- 3000
j <- 0
#ptm <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:M){
    sample(x = c(0, 1), size = X, replace = TRUE, prob = c(99.9, 0.1))
    j <- j + sum(.Last.value)
}
#proc.time() - ptm
j
```

I get 0 as expected.

However, when I un-comment the two lines currently commented out, I get numbers like 377984922.

What's going on?

Comment: Put `Lv <- .Last.value;message(paste(".Last.value:", Lv, "\n"));j <- j + sum(Lv)` after the call to `sample` to see what's in `?.Last.value`.

Comment: Interesting! @RuiBarradas I get very strange numbers in `Lv`. But the output of the call to `sample` should always be a vector of 0 and/or 1. What's going on here? What are these strange numbers in `Lv`?

Comment: I don't know where they come from but I believe they come from `proc.time`. I tried creating a `new.env` and assigning to `env$Lv` but the results were the same. To make it crazier, try printing `Lv` and `.Last.value` after the loop.

Comment: I mean `proc.time() - ptm;.Last.value;env$Lv`.

Comment: If you put the entire code in a function, for instance with no arguments, `f <- function(){code}` and call `f()` it will work as expected, the return value `j` is zero.

Comment: It definitely comes from `proc.time`. Wrap `system.time` around the loop and everything works as expected.